# Unit-test multiple c++ projects and export results to TeamCity

Tags: c++, unit-testing, teamcity, multiple-projects

I am introducing unit testing with Google Tests in my c++ projects.

The projects are organized in multiple solutions, each solution containing one (main) project and its dependencies. There is also one build solution, containing all projects.

Each project will add its own [project]_test project to the solution.

The unit tests can be run locally for each project, for each solution.

The build solution will have to be built using TeamCity.

**The problem:**

Google Tests provide an xml output that can be imported by TeamCity, to get test reports. But TeamCity is only capable of importing a single xml.

Manufacturing a compound xml from all the reports from different projects changes the formatting expected by TeamCity, so the xml is no longer read.

So far I have been unable to find anything that is capable of running multiple c++ projects, running tests, and obtaining test results, in TeamCity.

What are my options ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mihaela

You could use [XML Report processing Build Feature](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/XML+Report+Processing). It may process multiple xml files and import test results. Further information you can find in documentation.

So you don't need to compound xmls and may build all project at once.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I have been testing it with a single xml file, and completely overlooked the option of using wildcards. I found that out late yesterday...